# Going to the next scene in the built index order

Tags: c#, monodevelop, unity-game-engine, scene-manager

I have this piece of code for going to the next scene when the space pressed in built index order (for example , scene a is number 0 , scene b is number 1 and ... ) , but it doesn't work .

```
void Update () {

    if (Input.GetKey (KeyCode.Space)) {
        int nextSceneIndex = SceneManager.GetActiveScene ().buildIndex + 1;
        SceneManager.LoadScene (nextSceneIndex);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Do you get some error? Does it change to the wrong scene? Does it change scene at all? What is the code inside `SceneManager.LoadScene`? With a little bit more of detail I could actually help you.

Answer (score 1):

Add `using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;` to the top of your script, also make sure you add the level to the build index through file > build options.